# How do you pass a double quote as an argument to python script from C#?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, arguments, escaping, double-quotes

My ultimate goal, is to pass a 'json string' from C# to python script.

For instance, in python script, I would like to get as sys.argv[1], something along these lines:

```
'{"A":"Hello", "B":"world"}'
```

Then, I would be able to use:

```
mystring = sys.argv[1]
myjson = json.loads(mystring)
```

I am not able to get the above. And so, I even tried just getting this:

```
{"A":"Hello", "B":"world"}
```

(so that, I could add the first and last single quotes manually in python).

Unfortunately, in either case, I am unable to pass the double quotes.

In C#, I have tried:

```
string myarguments = "main.py \"{\"A\":\"Hello\", \"B\":\"world\"}\"";
var myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path_OF_PYTHON_EXE);
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myarguments;
var myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();
```

The part I am struggling with is to get the correct string **myarguments** that will allow the python script to receive a double quote as an argument.

With the above C# snippet, the python script:

```
import sys
print(str(sys.argv))
print('arg0 : ' + sys.argv[0])
print('arg1 : ' + sys.argv[1])
```

prints the following:

```
['main.py', '{A:Hello, B:world}']
arg0 : main.py
arg1 : {A:Hello, B:world}
```

What I really want in python, is to get from the line: print('arg1 : ' + sys.argv[1]):

```
arg1 : {"A":"Hello", "B":"world"}
```

Or even better:

```
arg1 : '{"A":"Hello", "B":"world"}'
```

I have tried many other scenarios (trying to escape double quotes in C#), but none of them gave me the correct sys.argv in python. Any help on this is very appreciated!

Comment: Try using double (double) quotes `\"\"`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the way:

In C#:

```
string myarguments = "main.py \"{\"\"A\"\":\"\"Hello\"\", \"\"B\"\":\"\"world\"\"}\" ";
```

In python, print(str(sys.argv)) prints:

```
['main.py', '{"A":"Hello","B":"world"}']
```